# Connect domain with server already having different nameserver

Tags: linux, domain, hosting

My server is using CWP (Centos Web Panel) and it already has a nameserver configured in it like ns1.myserver.com and ns2.myserver.com

I want to host another domain on that server but don't want to use same nameservers. I want to use my own nameservers like ns1.mynewdomain.com and ns2.mynewdomain.com

Is that something i can configure in my domain registrar? My registrar is having option to add A-Record, CNAME and TXT in their panel.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use my own nameservers like ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com. Is that something I can configure in my domain registrar?

Many registrars allow their customers to specify the nameservers attached to a given domain. Theoretically, though, they could choose to not offer this option (forcing you to use their own DNS services exclusively). But this would depend on the registrar.

> My registrar has the option to add A, CNAME and TXT records in their panel.

It does sound like the registrar is offering their own DNS services by default, in addition to domain registration. You would need to go through their control panel to determine if you have the option to manually set nameservers for your new domain. In my experience, this is often under some "Advanced" options for the domain, if it's available.

> I want to host another domain on that [CWP] server but I don't want to use the same nameservers [already configured in CWP].

Then you'll likely need to:

1. Specify the nameservers you wish to use for your new domain with your domain registrar.
2. Ensure that those nameservers are available and are properly configured to map any requests for your new domain to your CWP server. This might be via a separate DNS server, but as an FYI, it does appear that CWP allows you to add additional nameserver entries.
3. Configure the Apache process on your CWP server (e.g. under something like *Apache Settings -> Apache Include Conf -> vhosts.conf*) to respond to requests for whatever new domain you want the CWP server to handle.